# Connection between local directory and remote repository lost

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, github-desktop

I have a local directory that I created by cloning a remote repository about a year back. I have made many hundreds of changes to my local code since then, but the git files no longer exist in the directory, meaning the connection to the remote repository has been lost. At the same time, many hundreds of changes were made to the remote repository since I first cloned it.

Now, I want re-form that connection, and pull any new updates from the remote repository into my local directory.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: what does it mean that you've lost the connection? Was the remote repo moved to a new location? deleted? What have you tried to do and what was the error message(s)?

Comment: @Serge The git files in the local directory no longer exist.

Comment: Have you lost your `.git` directory in the local repository?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I have.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments you have lost your .git repository and your directory has a lot of updates from the last time you synced with the remote.

If you lost your .git repository then you cannot restore any commit which happened between the last push from you lost repository till it got lost.

What you can do, is to create another local repository from the remote one and manually merge your files into it.

1. `git clone your-remote-repo your-local-repo`
2. `git checkout -b your-restore-branch`, just make a different branch for restoring
3. copy your files itno *your-local-repo*
4. `git diff --name-status` will show the differences between the tip of the branch and the files which you copied
5. manually review all the differences and decide what you want to do with them
6. when you done your merge work, commit all the changes in the *your-restore-branch* by `git commit`; You might want to do several commits. do testing.
7. check out the original branch `git checkout master` (or whatever branch name you had)
8. `git merge your-restore-branch --squash` merge into the main branch, ignoring your manual merge history. then do your testing again and `git commit` for the results of the merge.
9. when you done, you can do `git push` into the remote repo.